# org.openqa.selenium.ElementNotVisibleException: element not visible (Session info: chrome=55.0.2883.87)

Tags: java, google-chrome, selenium, accordion

Please help with my Selenium code. I'm just a beginner and can't figure out what's wrong with my code. Error message:

```
Accordion down arrow clicked.
Time found.
FAILED: homeLoan("Janet Jones", "janet.jones@testing.com", "Australia", "4569", "62365898563", "Home Loan", "Buying", "150000", "55000")
org.openqa.selenium.ElementNotVisibleException: element not visible
  (Session info: chrome=55.0.2883.87)
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.25.426923 (0390b88869384d6eb0d5d09729679f934aab9eed),platform=Windows NT 10.0.14393 x86_64) (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)
Command duration or timeout: 25 milliseconds
Build info: version: '2.53.1', revision: 'a36b8b1cd5757287168e54b817830adce9b0158d', time: '2016-06-30 19:26:09'
System info: host: 'DEV-TEST-01', ip: '172.30.60.20', os.name: 'Windows NT (unknown)', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '10.0', java.version: '1.8.0_112'
Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver
Capabilities [{applicationCacheEnabled=false, rotatable=false, mobileEmulationEnabled=false, networkConnectionEnabled=false, chrome={chromedriverVersion=2.25.426923 (0390b88869384d6eb0d5d09729679f934aab9eed), userDataDir=C:\Users\adm-cxc\AppData\Local\Temp\2\scoped_dir3468_7348}, takesHeapSnapshot=true, pageLoadStrategy=normal, databaseEnabled=false, handlesAlerts=true, hasTouchScreen=false, version=55.0.2883.87, platform=XP, browserConnectionEnabled=false, nativeEvents=true, acceptSslCerts=true, locationContextEnabled=true, webStorageEnabled=true, browserName=chrome, takesScreenshot=true, javascriptEnabled=true, cssSelectorsEnabled=true}]
Session ID: eba36d4b2bcab09b464da0fbf99e681d
```

My code can click the down arrow of the accordion and also the time to be selected that has a checkbox. However, my code cannot click that checkbox of the preferred time.

```
System.out.println("Switched to pop up window.");

driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='modalBookAppointment']/div/div/div/h4"));
System.out.println("When would you like us to call you? found.");

driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(50, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
driver.findElement(By.xpath("(//*[@class='fa fa-chevron-down'])[3]")).click();
System.out.println("Accordion down arrow clicked.");

driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(50, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='p_lt_ctl00_Firstmac_RetailHardSellBookAppointment_BookAppointment_AppointmentDatesRepeater_ctl01_BookAppointment_AppointmentsRepeater_ctl12_AppointmentSelection_Vacant']/div[1]/input"));
System.out.println("Time found.");

driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='p_lt_ctl00_Firstmac_RetailHardSellBookAppointment_BookAppointment_AppointmentDatesRepeater_ctl01_BookAppointment_AppointmentsRepeater_ctl12_AppointmentSelection_Vacant']/div[1]/input")).click();;
System.out.println("Time selected.");
```

I'm trying to select the Morning 9:00 time, the first highlighted from the screenshot.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8AUvJ.jpg)

Any help will do. Thank you in advance.

Comment: I think the used XPath is not valid.

Comment: It printed out the "Time found". It's having the error on .click();

Comment: The element might be visible, but that element might not be clickable, please check my answer and see if its correct

Comment: also giving the error: org.openqa.selenium.TimeoutException: Expected condition failed: waiting for element to be clickable: By.xpath:

Comment: That means it cannot be clicked. Are you sure the element is visible at the time you call the `click`method? Otherwise you could try to use an Action chane, although it might give the same problems.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that your xpath is not correct. Yours is pointing to the `input` tag, while the part in thr immage points to the `div` element right before that.

In the image you posted there is the complete correct path shown in at the top of the 'firePath' tab. Try to use that one instead and let us know if it worked out.

Edit:
You can try the following to see if its a time based problem.

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 15);
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(yourXPath));
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. The xpath for the checkbox inside the accordion is: //*[@id='p_lt_ctl00_Firstmac_RetailHardSellBookAppointment_BookAppointment_AppointmentDatesRepeater_ctl01_BookAppointment_AppointmentsRepeater_ctl03_AppointmentSelection_Vacant']/div[1]/input

Comment: Im trying now the one without /input at the end

Comment: I edited my answer, please see if this solved your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try to wait for some time till target element becomes visible:

```
JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;  
js.executeScript('document.querySelector("input[type='checkbox']").style.display="block";');

WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10);
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//input[@type='checkbox']")));
```

Comment: tried this and still not working. error: org.openqa.selenium.TimeoutException: Expected condition failed: waiting for visibility of element located by By.xpath: //input[@type='checkbox'] (tried for 15 second(s) with 500 MILLISECONDS interval)

Answer (score 0):

I have already resolved this issue by changing the xpath to //*[@id='p_lt_ctl00_Firstmac_RetailHardSellBookAppointment_BookAppointment_AppointmentDatesRepeater_ctl01_BookAppointment_AppointmentsRepeater_ctl12_AppointmentSelection_Vacant']